# Is there a way to get a list of all installed iphone apps?

Tags: iphone

is there a possibility to get a list of all installed apps in my app? I don't need all information of the installed apps, but a title or an "id" would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this is not possible when you're creating an app for the App Store.

Comment: Do you know if this is possible for the enterprise version?

Comment: I think the "reverse" way could be possible, but you have to check for existing apps or URL handlers.